# Creating coordinates for polygon using Python lists

Tags: python

I want to make an algorithm that will create coordinates (corner coordinates) for square polygons. See the picture below:

[image]

I have written some code so far, but only for the X-axis, and I think it could be improved.

My desired output should be two nested lists, one for X and one for Y. There should be 25 polygons (5x5):

```
X_list = [[0, 5, 5, 0], [5, 10, 10, 5], [10, 15, 15, 10], ...]
Y_list = [[0, 0, 5, 5] , [0, 0, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 5], ...]
```

This is the code that I have. How can I make it work, so that it can make polygons on Y-axis too.

```
max_x = 20
max_y = 20

x = 0
y = 0

xlist = []
ylist = []

lon = []
lad = []
while x < max_x and y < max_y:

    xlist = []
    ylist = []

    x = x
    y = y
    xlist.append(x)
    ylist.append(y)

    x += 5
    y = y
    xlist.append(x)
    ylist.append(y)

    x = x
    y += 5
    xlist.append(x)
    ylist.append(y)

    x -= 5
    y = y
    xlist.append(x)
    ylist.append(y)
    x += 5
    y -= 5

    lon.append(xlist)
    lad.append(ylist)

print(lon)
print(lad)
```

Comment: why do you have lines like `x = x` and `y = y`? Also what exactly seems to be the problem? what output you *are* getting

Comment: problem is that this code makes polygons only on X, not on Y
I want to get list of polygons , 5x5 .

Comment: @taga great question format!

Comment: Your code does produce Y. you have to specify more accuratly 1) what you are trying to get, 2) what you are actually getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using list comprehensions.

```
x_count = 5
y_count = 5
step = 5

x_list = y_count * [[i*step,(i+1)*step,(i+1)*step,i*step] for i in range(x_count)]
y_list = [[i*step,i*step,(i+1)*step,(i+1)*step] for i in range(y_count) for j in range(x_count)]
```

Comment: thanks!
How would this code change, if I do not increase coordinates by 5, but by some other value , for example decimal (0.005)?

Comment: just change all the 5 values except the first one and the ones in the ranges to .005

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo for the update. I was part way through it but you saved me the trouble and put the x_count & y_count in the right places which is tricky.

Comment: Extending @Tomerikoo's answer I simplified the statements a little by modifying the range instead of multiplying each element by `step`.

Comment: Nice! yes it is tricky to understand and some might say not pythonicly readable, but once you figure it out it's very neat. nice solution. upvoted :)

Comment: Also, an interesting note will be that `step` can also be divided to `x_step` and `y_step` thus creating rectangles and not only squares

Comment: Thanks, and what If I want to start number be  30 for example, not 0?

Comment: Also, this solution is good, but It does not work if I want to set my coordinates to increase on every 0.1 (It does not work for decimal numbers because of range)

Comment: @taga right. I should have left it alone. I'll change it back. It seemed like a good idea at the time :-)

Comment: Please do :)
Also, how can I set the start point for x and y?

Comment: Done. The easiest way to change the start point is to use the range, although in that case you are specifying it in steps. So if step is .1, to start at x=1 instead of x=0 you would use `range(10, x_count+10)`, and you may have issues if you want to offset in fractions of a step. If you want to use absolute offset, you would have to add it to each of the 4 elements, like `[i*step+offset,(i+1)*step+offset,(i+1)*step+offset,i*step+offset]`